# Could I use Bootstrap columns to create this section, and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

How I can make right column responsive and fullwidth to the right side? For now I have this html:

```
<section class="values">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="values-info">
                <div class="values-info-logo">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                </div>
                <h3 class="values-info-title">Our values</h3>
                <p class="values-info-subtitle">On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col md-6">
            <ul class="values-info-list">
                <li>Real</li>
                <li>Honest</li>
                <li>Inspired</li>
                <li>Driven</li>
                <li>Equal</li>
                <li>Purposeful</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have idea to make  position absolute and give some width but it will not work responsive, does bootstrap can solve it ?

Design section here:

[image: Section Values]

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="values">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="values-info">
                <div class="values-info-logo">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                </div>
                <h3 class="values-info-title">Our values</h3>
                <p class="values-info-subtitle">On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col md-6">
            <ul class="values-info-list">
                <li>Real</li>
                <li>Honest</li>
                <li>Inspired</li>
                <li>Driven</li>
                <li>Equal</li>
                <li>Purposeful</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.css

```
.values{
  background-image: url("test.jpg");
  height: 100%; 
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I think this will achieve your visual design.